# How do i use EasyTabs Rename Function With CefSharp

Tags: tabs, visual-studio-2019, cefsharp

I'm making a cefsharp web browser in VB.2019 I'm using C#, I was wondering if anyone has a solution to EasyTabs not showing the name of what website I'm on, I didn't implement the code Because I don't know what to write, for example, when I load my browser it only shows "New Tab" I need it to show the site the consumer is on on the tab there on as well, someone please help. I am using .NET Framework 4.7.2

Comment: Have a look at the EasyTabs example. See https://github.com/lstratman/EasyTabs/blob/master/TestApp/TabWindow.cs#L14

Comment: what code am I supposed to be looking for

Comment: http://cefsharp.github.io/api/84.4.x/html/E_CefSharp_WinForms_ChromiumWebBrowser_TitleChanged.htm occurs when the title changes, which is likely what you are after. Try download and run the example if you need to get a better understanding.

Comment: I’ve tried to run the example project but it just comes up with a error, to fix the error I tried creating an EXE file using the rebuild method and when I did it still came up with the same thing I don’t know the aero directly when I get a chance yes I will paste it in the comments

Comment: Build the solution,  close visual studio,  try build again. Easy tabs is not a project I actually use.

Comment: it says "a project with an output type of Class Library Cannot Be Started Directly" then it wants me to create an Executable, isent visual studio supposed to do that its-self